# Admob use bank account in another country

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I am asking about admob bank account settings,

Can i use bank account in another country than the account country ?

My account country is Egypt, but now i am living in KSA, so can i use bank account in KSA to receive my payments from my Egyptian account ?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Googling it again, I found that it is not possible, It is not possible. this quote from Google helps the website.

"No. You can't add a bank account that's not based in your country. Please enter the bank account that matches your Payee profile address. Please also make sure that the country code in your SWIFT code matches the country code in your AdSense account. For example, if your SWIFT code is “KZKOKZKXXXX”, “KZKO” is the code for the name of the bank, “KZ” is the country code and “KXXXX” is the code for the branch.
My bank account number has hyphens. Should I enter the hyphens when giving my bank account information?
Do I need to enter the intermediary bank information?
"

Comment: Have you contacted google itseld and received that answer?

Comment: @ThanosF Yes, they said that this not possible, you have to create a new account with the new country